# Ruby UTF 8 Decryption Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption

after decrypting a hash, method `decrypt(hash[field])` is returning:

```
"100\xE2\x80\x90111\xE2\x80\x9010333\xE2\x80\x900012"
```

but using `puts decrypt(hash[field])` gives correct result as

```
'100‐111‐10333‐0012'
```

how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `decrypt` method is returning binary data, not the UTF-8 encoded string you're expecting. The bytes `"\xE2\x80\x90"` are `‐`:

```
puts '‐'.bytes.map { |b| b.to_s(16) }
# e2
# 80
# 90
```

or:

```
puts '‐'.force_encoding('binary').inspect
# "\xE2\x80\x90"
```

If you're sure you're getting a UTF-8 string, then fix the encoding:

```
# UTF-8 is the default so we force binary to start
bytes = "100\xE2\x80\x90111\xE2\x80\x9010333\xE2\x80\x900012".force_encoding('binary')
# "100\xE2\x80\x90111\xE2\x80\x9010333\xE2\x80\x900012" 
puts bytes.force_encoding('utf-8')
# 100‐111‐10333‐0012
```

Comment: `decrypt(hash[field]).force_encoding('binary').force_encoding('utf-8')` working, thanks. not sure if my PR will be approved though.

Comment: You should be okay with just `decrypt(hash[field]).force_encoding('utf-8')`, I used `force_encoding('binary')` in the example because the default encoding is UTF-8.